# Replace on for loop list

Tags: python, anonymize

My ideia is to find every email in a sentence and replace it for a different random email (anonymization). But I can't get the result I want. Every email is replaced for the same one or I get an error (list index out of range)

input:
email = "daniel@hotmail.com sent it to ana@gmail.com"

output I want
email = "albert@hotmail.com sent it to john@gmail.com"

```
random_emails = ["albert", "john", "mary"]


def find_email(email: str):
    result = email
    i = 0
    email_address = r"\S+@"
    for text in email:
            result = re.sub(email_address, random_emails[i] + "@", result)
            i += 1
    return result

print(find_email(email))
```

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: As it stands, I think the organization/design of your program could really be improved. I would recommend working on that before anything else. Oh, and your regex to find emails is woefully incomplete, although I'm guessing you were aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but note that identical emails will be anonymized in the same way. I let you try this :

```
import re

email = "daniel@hotmail.com sent it to ana@gmail.com"
random_emails = ["albert", "john", "mary"]

def find_email(email: str):
    result = email
    i = 0
    email_address = r"\S+@"
    regex_matches = re.findall(email_address, email)
    for match in regex_matches:
        result = result.replace(match, random_emails[i] + "@")
        i += 1
    return result

print(find_email(email))
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need for loop, and I think your RegExr can be improved

```
def find_email(email):
    result = email
    email_address = r"(\w+@)(\w+.* )(\w+@)(\w+.*)"
    a='AAAAA@'
    b='BBBBB@'
    result = re.sub(email_address, rf'{a}\2{b}\4', result)
    return result


email = "daniel@hotmail.com sent it to ana@gmail.com"
print(find_email(email))
```

> Explaining:
>
> You can create substitution groups:
>
> 1º = 1º email 2º = server and texts 3º = 2º email 4º = server.com
>
> And now, you just need to replace \1 and \2 with everythink you want
>
> example2: Your new routine

```
import re
from random import seed
from random import randint

random_emails = ["albert", "john", "mary"]


def find_email(email):
    result = email
    email_address = r"(\w+@)(\w+.* )(\w+@)(\w+.*)"
    first = randint(0, 2)
    second = randint(0, 2)
    while first == second:
        second = randint(0, 2)
    result = re.sub(email_address, rf'{random_emails[first]}@\2{random_emails[second]}@\4', result)
    return result


email = "daniel@hotmail.com sent it to ana@gmail.com"
print(find_email(email))
```

> I used random to generate an random number to got emails from list.
>   And  "while first == second:" just to not repeat first and second
>   emails

Comment: I used random to generate an random number to got emails from list. And  "while first == second:" just to not repeat first and second emails randomic got.